# arrays empilhadas

Tags: javascript, array

dei uma busca pela internet e não encontrei resposta para este meu problema. Imagine que vc tem arrays empilhadas. Por exemplo:

```
var array = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [9, 10]]];
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é pegar as menores arrays possíveis e ordená-las dentro de apenas uma array. Assim:

```
array = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]];
```

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode criar um método que percorre os itens do seu `array` e:

- Caso encontre um elemento, adiciona o `array` de origem ao resultado;
- Caso encontre um `array`, percorra este para verificar se possui outros `arrays` ou elementos de outro tipo.

```js
const array = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [9, 10]]];

const percorrer = (item, resultado = []) => {
  for (const subitem of item) {
    if (Array.isArray(subitem)) {
      percorrer(subitem, resultado);
    } else {
      resultado.push(item);
      break;
    }
  }

  return resultado;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(percorrer(array)));
```

Você também pode usar a função [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para gerar o `array` de destino verificando o tipo do `array`:

```js
const array = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[[5, 6], [7, 8]], [9, 10]]];

// Checa se é um array de arrays
const checar = (array) => array.reduce((acumulador, item) => Array.isArray(item) ? acumulador : false, true);

const reducer = (acumulador, item) => checar(item) ? acumulador.concat(amassar(item)) : acumulador.concat([item]);

const amassar = (origem) => origem.reduce(reducer, []);

console.log(amassar(array));
```

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```